# JQuery: simple menu animate and content show/hide

Tags: jquery, css

Mostly Working Fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/7nrZ6/40/

```
    $('#inav .opt').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:1});
});
$('.opt').mouseout(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
    {
        $(this).animate({opacity:1});
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).animate({opacity:.25});
    }
});
$('.opt').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected'))
    {                
        $('.selected').animate({opacity:.25});
        $('.opt').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected'); 
        $(this).animate({opacity:1});
    }
});

$("#buttons img").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#pages div").css("display", "none");
    $("#page-" + id).css("display", "block");
});
```

My fiddle is mostly working. I have 2 questions to finish it off.

The mouseover/out animation seems to stack, so if I wave my mouse over it a bunch of times, it will play the animation according to how many times it registered the over/out. Kind of annoying. I was using hover before with a stop function, but couldn't figure out how to do the click portion with it. How can I set it to not stack over/out registrations?

I want my content divs to all be hidden at first, then appear/disappear according to button clicked. As it is now, they are all visible. When I set the #pages id to display none, none of the pages unhide when button is clicked. Not sure if JS is even needed for this kind of functionality. If there is an easier way, please advise.

I'm sure these are simple fixes. I'm learning as I go. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AsuAf/)**

You can use this css rule to hide them:

```
#pages > div[id^="page"]
{
    display:none;
}
```

And you can use `mouseenter/mouseleave` (This is actual **hover**) instead of `mouseover/mouseout` and use `.stop()` to cleanup any previous animation from running on frequent hovers and simplify it to:

```
$('#inav .opt').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1});
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: $(this).is('.selected') ? 1 : .25});
});

$('.opt').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.is('.selected'))
    {                
        $('.selected').stop().animate({opacity:.25}); 
        $('.opt').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected').stop().animate({opacity:1}); 
    }
});

$("#buttons img").click(function () {
    $("#page-" + this.id).show().siblings('div[id^="page"]').hide();
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly and is more elegant. Thank you! 
I wonder if you could help with a new problem? See updated fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5QnT/4/)
I'm trying to add an image slider within the gallery (page-2) div. The slider is nested within another div and doesn't show with the click. I've tried to simplify it using text placeholders.

Comment: Issue is with button img click so changed it to  `$("#buttons img").click(function () {
    $("#page-" + this.id).show().siblings('div[id^="page"]').hide();
});`